# rgb to ycbcr conversion in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-conversion

I am trying to write a function in Matlab that takes an RGB image of class unit8 and double and converts it to a YCBCR image. The transformation formula is below.

[image: The transformation between YCbCr and RGB]

I would be really thankful for any help of any kind.

Comment: Have a look at this [page](http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php), here you will find all information needed regarding yuv, rgb and the conversion between them; including sample code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/) function for that, if you have access to it: [RGB2YCBCR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/rgb2ycbcr.html)

If you don't have access to it, here's how you can do the conversion yourself:

```
rgbImage = imread('peppers.png');  %# A sample RGB image
A = [65.481 -37.797 112; ...       %# A 3-by-3 matrix of scale factors
     128.553 -74.203 -93.786; ...
     24.966 112 -18.214];

%# First convert the RGB image to double precision, scale its values to the
%#   range 0 to 1, reshape it to an N-by-3 matrix, and multiply by A:
ycbcrImage = reshape(double(rgbImage)./255,[],3)*A;

%# Shift each color plane (stored in each column of the N-by-3 matrix):
ycbcrImage(:,1) = ycbcrImage(:,1)+16;
ycbcrImage(:,2) = ycbcrImage(:,2)+128;
ycbcrImage(:,3) = ycbcrImage(:,3)+128;

%# Convert back to type uint8 and reshape to its original size:
ycbcrImage = reshape(uint8(ycbcrImage),size(rgbImage));
```

And here's the image you get when you display `ycbcrImage`:

[image]

Comment: I need to implement it though.

Comment: @biz: [gnovice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311460/rgb-to-ycbcr-conversion-in-matlab/6311484#6311484) has provided an implementation based on your transformation formula

Comment: THANKS A LOT for your answer, if you don't mind can you just give a quick explaination to the two reshapes ?

Comment: AWESOME!! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @biz: When you reshape the N-by-M-by-3 RGB image into an N*M-by-3 matrix, the red values are in the first column, the green values are in the second column, and the blue values are in the third column. This is because RESHAPE will draw elements from the 3-dimensional matrix column-wise then page-wise (i.e. `rgbImage(:,1,1)`, then `rgbImage(:,2,1)`, ... , `rgbImage(:,M-1,3)`, `rgbImage(:,M,3)`). Using `[]` as an argument to RESHAPE tells it to figure out what that value should be. The second reshape simply reverses the process.

Comment: thanks!! I am also trying to do the `function ycbcr = rgbtoycbcr(rgbImage)` so I can get the image to convert as an argument but I get : rgbImage not defined

Answer (score 0):

### "rgb2ycbcr" function (image processing toolbox):

**Path** :

*MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\images\colorspaces\rgb2ycbcr.m*

**Code** :

```
function ycbcr = rgb2ycbcr(varargin)
rgb = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
isColormap = false;

if (ndims(rgb) == 2)
 isColormap=true;
 colors = size(rgb,1);
 rgb = reshape(rgb, [colors 1 3]);
end

origT = [65.481 128.553 24.966;-37.797 -74.203 112; 112 -93.786 -18.214];
origOffset = [16;128;128];


scaleFactor.double.T = 1/255;      
scaleFactor.double.offset = 1/255; 
scaleFactor.uint8.T = 1/255;       
scaleFactor.uint8.offset = 1;      
scaleFactor.uint16.T = 257/65535;  
scaleFactor.uint16.offset = 257;   

classIn = class(rgb);
T = scaleFactor.(classIn).T * origT;
offset = scaleFactor.(classIn).offset * origOffset;


ycbcr = zeros(size(rgb),classIn);

for p = 1:3
 ycbcr(:,:,p) = imlincomb(T(p,1),rgb(:,:,1),T(p,2),rgb(:,:,2), T(p,3),rgb(:,:,3),offset(p));
end  

if isColormap
 ycbcr = reshape(ycbcr, [colors 3 1]);
end
```