# Converting colors from RGB to YCbCr packing image

Tags: java, image, processing, rgb

I am creating image compressing program and I want to convert colors from RBG to YCbCr, I dont have problems extracting image into pixels and getting RBG information from each pixel, however, I have no idea how to pack pixels together with new YCbCr information to produce new image.

I wrote code where I manipulate RGB information and put it back together and it looks like this:

```
private static int packPixel(int red, int green, int blue) {
   return (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
}

public BufferedImage makeNewBufferedImage(short[][] ImageDataRed, short[][] ImageDataGreen, short[][] ImageDataBlue ) {
   int[] newBufferedImageData = new int[rows * cols];
   int index;
   for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
       for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
           index = (row * cols) + col;
           newBufferedImageData[index] = packPixel(ImageDataRed[row][col], ImageDataGreen[row][col], ImageDataBlue[row][col]);
       }
   }
```

I know that YCbCr holds more information but I am out of ideas how to pack it together, maybe anyone could help me?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311460/rgb-to-ycbcr-conversion-in-matlab  Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr Still one more :) http://www.equasys.de/colorconversion.html

Answer (score 1):

[Java Advanced Imaging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-1-0-2-140451.html) seems to support YCbCr.