# Construct single column matrix from the rows of another matrix with multiple columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, rgb

I'm learning about image processing, and currently translating between RGB and YCbCr.

Basically, I have a nxmx3 matrix, which represents the brightness of each colour (RGB), and the operation to change this to Y,Cb, and Cr would be something like this:

```
for each row, index, in RGBMatrix:
    y[index] = row[0] + row[1] + row[2]
```

So each row of y has one value, and that value is based on the values in the same in RGBMatrix.

I've tried the following in MATLAB:

```
function [y,Cb, Cr] = rgbToYCbCr(r,g,b)

signalSize = size(r);
y = zeros(signalSize);
for i = 1:signalSize(1)
  for j = 1:signalSize(2)
      y(i,j,1) = (0.299 * r(i,j,1)) + (0.587 * g(i,j,2)) + (0.114 * b(i,j,3));
  end
end
end
```

However, this does not give me the results that I want as y now has the same dimensions as the RGBMatrix, when instead it should be 1 column.

How can I do this efficiently in MATLAB?

I know there is an inbuilt function for RGB to YCbCr, but for the sake of learning I'd like to implement it myself.

### Example:

RGB Matrix:

```
  R G B
[[0.5,0.5,0.5],
 [0.2,0.1,0.6],
 [0.1,0.4,0.7]]
```

Y Matrix:

```
[[0.5+0.5+0.5],
 [-0.2-0.1+0.6],
 [0.1+0.4-0.7]]
```

or

```
[[1.5],
 [0.3],
 [-0.2]]
```

Ignore the fact that values aren't realistic, what I'm more concerned about is carrying out an operation per row like I've described in Matlab without using the (typically) slower iterative way (with a for loop).

In reality I have a 1080x768x3 array. Each element in the 1080x768 dimension has a value for each colour (R,G,B) and I want to convert this to (Y,Cb,Cr) eventually.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What are `r`, `g`, and `b` in your example? Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6311460/52738) helps?

Comment: @gnovice hopefully the example helps

Comment: "However, this does not give me the results that I want as y now has the same dimensions as the RGBMatrix, when instead it should be 1 column." .... No? If you have a color transformation, the output should have the same shape as the input, most definitely. In your numerical example, `r` is 1x3, so are `b` and `g` therefore `y` is 1x3. In the real case, `r` `b` and `g` are each 1080x768, so must be `y`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri my y is 1080x768x3 though, which surely doesn't make any sense as each pixel has only one value for luminance right?

Comment: The, that must be because you defined `r` `b` and `g` wrong. If you were to show a [mcve] as required we coudl help more

Comment: r is the original signal matrix (1080x768x3) with all the values in the blue and green dimensions zeroed so that image(r) would show only the red values

Comment: @JordanMackie that is clearly wrong. That is good for `image` so your eyes can see red, but that is not what the red channels is. A number is not `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0]`, thats a vector. Zeros count. `r` should be uniquely the data in the red channel

Comment: In your new (and worse) code than before, define `signalSize =[size(r,1),size(r,2)];` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an RGB image, `Imgrgb` that is `NxMx3` in size, do:

```
Imgrgb= imread('peppers.png');  % A sample RGB image
% make sure you have a double image range [0-1], you may not need this.
Imgrgb=im2double(Imgrgb);

r=Imgrgb(:,:,1);
g=Imgrgb(:,:,2);
b=Imgrgb(:,:,3);

y = (0.299 * r) + (0.587 * g) + (0.114 * b);

Cb=
Cr=

% concatenate result:
ImgYCbCr=cat(3,y,Cb,Cr);
```

And `y` shoudl be `NxM`, the same as `r`,`g`, and `b`. Do the same for the other 2 values with their corresponding equation.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is like:

```
A =
     1     3     5
     2     4     6
```

then you may "flatten" it to a vector like:

```
>>Av = A(:)
Av =
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
```

I.e. it takes the values from the matrix in a **row order** and converts to a vector.
To convert it back to a matrix you may use the `reshape` function

```
>> reshape(Av,[2 3])
ans =
     1     3     5
     2     4     6
```

The `A(:)` method is equivalent to `reshape(A,[numel(A) 1])`

Comment: Matlab is column-major, so it takes the values per **column** before it moves in the row-direction. Otherwise, this is the right answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, that's not quite what I'm looking for, hopefully the example clears things up